# Loading Powerpoint Array from Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to have powerpoint macro populate an array by taking data from excel file. In fact, there are two arrays. Same code, same file, but one array gets populated and the other one doesn't (or gets only partially populated). Below, FindList array is working fine and ReplaceList does not. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions for an alternative method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Multi_FindReplace()

Dim FindList As Variant
Dim ReplaceList As Variant
Dim x, i, j As Long

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlBook As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\wip\dev\DRAFT Exhibits (Client) 04-06-18.xlsm")
xlBook.Application.Visible = False

FindList = xlBook.Worksheets("FindReplace").Range("A1:A22").Value
ReplaceList = xlBook.Worksheets("FindReplace").Range("B1:B22").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with using a single array to load all the data. Looks like this:

```
 ExcelData = xlBook.Worksheets("FindReplace").Range("A1:B22").value
```